# Array values not being added to Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a snippet of code that adds a submission as a new document to a submissions collection in Firestore, this submission contain multiple fields. The environment is JavaScript React Native.

I am dealing with a strange behaviour however:

```
const parent = db.collection('submissions').doc();

console.log(submission.facilities);
// output: ["CHANGING_FACILITIES"] // it's an array

batch.set(parent, {
  ...submission,
  facilitiess: submission.facilities
});

batch.commit();
```

For some reason the field named "facilities" is always pushed as an empty array. When I renamed the field to "facilitiess" (added an extra s just to debug) it was added correctly (see image below) even though the value is identical.

Can someone explain this? Is the word "facilities" reserved or is this possibly a bug?

[image]

**Update:** I implemented a cloud function as a workaround, it is also failing.

```
exports.fixArrayBug = functions.firestore
  .document('submissions/{id}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    try {
      await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('submissions')
        .doc(context.params.id)
        .update({
          facilities: snap.data().facilitiess,
          facilitiess: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Without seeing the entire code ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that reproduces the problem, it's impossible to tell what might be going on here.